# Images not loading before reload

Tags: javascript

I am not a real programmer but have done some small projects in JavaScript. I am now working on a small app backing up a scientific poster. The script works, but the cursor (cross) and the other field, both bit maps do not appear before the page is reloaded. Same behavior in several browsers. I found out that the onload function is not run. But the first one img is run. I don't understand why.
I did some googling and found references to the problem but did not really understand it.

Could somebody be so kind and help me?

I made a versjon with only the essential gode:
URL: http://folk.uio.no/gerald/IADMFR2017/test.html

Here is the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Increasing clinical relevance in oral radiology through computer-based examination?</title>    
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"></script>    
<script>
  function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.enableMouseOver();
    createjs.Touch.enable( stage );
    img = new Image();
    img.src = 'images/radiograph.png';
    img.onload = function(event) {
        var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap('images/radiograph.png');
        bitmap.x = 50;
        bitmap.y = 80;
        bitmap.on("click", handleMouseEvent);
        stage.addChild(bitmap);
        stage.update();
    }

    fieldIm  = new Image();
    fieldIm.src = 'images/field.png';
    var field;
    fieldIm.onload = function(event) {
        field = new createjs.Bitmap('images/field.png');
        field.scaleX=0.9;
        field.scaleY=0.9;
        field.x=400;
        field.y=100;
        field.visible = false;
        stage.addChild(field);
        stage.update();
    }

    crossIm  = new Image();
    crossIm.src = 'images/cross.png';
    var cross;
    crossIm.onload = function(event) {
        cross = new createjs.Bitmap('images/cross.png');
        cross.scaleX=0.5;
        cross.scaleY=0.5;
        cross.zIndex = 500;
        cross.visible = false;
        stage.addChild(cross);
        stage.update();
    }
    stage.update();

    function handleMouseEvent(evt) {
            cross.x = evt.rawX - 12;
            cross.y = evt.rawY - 12;
            cross.visible = true;
            stage.update();
    }

    var rect = new createjs.Rectangle(0, 0, 180, 30);
    var frg = '#FFFFFF';
    var bkg = '#000000';

    var container = new createjs.Container();
    container.x = 450;
    container.y = 500;
    var rectShape = new createjs.Shape();
    rectShape.graphics.c().f(bkg).dr(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
    var text = new createjs.Text("Check Result", "30px Arial", "#FFFFFF");
    container.addChild(rectShape);
    container.addChild(text);
    container.on("click", handleToggle);
    stage.addChild(container);
    stage.update();

    function handleToggle(evt) {
            field.visible = !field.visible;
            if (field.visible) {
                text.text="Hide Result";
            } else {
                text.text="Check Result";
            }
            stage.update();
    }

    stage.update();

  }


</script>    
</head>    
<body onload="init()">
    <H1>Poster ICDMFR 2017 Clickable task example</H1>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</body>    
</html>
```

I appreciate any help on that.
Greetings
Gerald
http://www.odont.uio.no/english/people/adm/fac/gerald

Comment: I loaded html from example and it all works. Image.onload methods get executed. What issue do you experience?

Comment: A lot of those `stage.update` calls in the init function are unnecessary. You just need one update to start (the one at the bottom will suffice), and then any time things change you can put another (in your onloads works fine).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Andrii: the problem is that the cross and field images don't show up when clicking on the image or button. They only do after the first reload of the page.

Comment: Thank you Lanny, I will try to remove the unnecessary reloads and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Hi Lanny, I tried now to remove all stage.updates() other than the last one. Now the image does not load at all before I press the button. That is why i addet all the updates in the first place, because the image did not appear. I think the problem lays somewhere else.

Comment: Something is happening on a reload that does noe happen the first time the page is loaded. What can that be? 
Same behavior in chrome, ie, android chrome and ipad chrome.

I am travelling, so I have limited access to the net. Please help me somebody